# Saving ArrayList into .txt file - Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to convert an ArrayList into a .txt file of my own class (admin) and its superclass (users). I'm saving data like name, surname, antiquity and stuff like that via JOptionPane requested in the main.

So far I've done this, but the problem is that the function stops working right before the writeObject.

Does not pop up any sort of error, i just get de try catch JOptionPane and i'm kinda stuck, will appreciate any help.

```
    public static void save_txt() {
    String PATH = null;
    try {
        File f;
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        int seleccion = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
        if (seleccion == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File JFC = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            PATH = JFC.getAbsolutePath();
            PATH = PATH + ".txt";
            f = new File(PATH);
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(fo);
            /**
             * ---Stops working there---
             */
            o.writeObject(singleton.ALadmin);
            o.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "TXT file saved correctly", "TXT file",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error saving TXT", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try printing the exception from the try-catch instead of ignoring it?

Comment: is singleton.ALadmin serializable (by that i mean does it implement the java.io.serializable interface? Also add e.printStackTrace() at the catch to get the actual error printed, and post it on a question edit.